# No reverse DNS (PTR) entries / I can't set PTR correctly

Tags: email, pointers, dns, spam, cwp

ERROR: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The problem MX records are:
111.150.112.185.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
You should contact your ISP and ask him to add a PTR record for your ips

I want my email not to be spammed and I need the ptr record to be set correctly

in dns setting:
`mydomain.com IN MX 10 mail.mydomain.com. mail.mydomain.com 14400 IN A 185.112.150.111 111.150.112.185.in-addr.arpa. 60 IN PTR mail.mydomain.com`